# Flutter charts, Place a text at center

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-layout

I am using [Flutter Charts](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) to create a doughnut chart.
I want to place a text inside the doughnut, along with a legend.

I tried using a `Center Widget` inside a `Stack Widget` but it doesn't put the text at the centre if I add a `DatumLegend` as a behaviour to the charts. 
If I remove the legend, it shows the text at the correct position.

My code from charts is:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    charts.PieChart(
      getseriesList(_values),
      animate: true,
      defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
          arcWidth: 40,
          arcRendererDecorators: [
            charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside)
          ]),
      defaultInteractions: true,
      behaviors: [
        charts.DatumLegend(
          position: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
          desiredMaxColumns: 4,
          legendDefaultMeasure: charts.LegendDefaultMeasure.none,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
        child: Text(
          'CenterText',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black38,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Here, I want the `99` to be placed at the center. 
[image: .]

Comment: can you show an image of what the current code looks like?

Comment: added screen shot

Comment: Try wrapping both the chart and the text with a Center widget.

Comment: tried that, it doesn't work. The problem is that the legend is also part of the same widget and thus take some space. Now, the centre widget places the text at the centre of what is chart + legend.

Answer (score 2):

Use alignment: Alignment.center from Stack.

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: pieCard(widget.items),
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(label),
          Text('R\$ 2.500,0'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Positioned widget instead center in stack.
To keep widget center horizontal:

```
Positioned(
    left : 0,
    right : 0,
    child : <your widget>,
)
```

To keep widget center vertical:

```
Positioned(
    top : 0,
    bottom : 0,
    child : <your widget>,
)
```

This works for me :)

Comment: this didn't work for me, the positioned widget was placed at the top left.

Comment: positioned widget remains top left as default. To keep it horizontal center, you have to give left and right value 0. I guess you must not have provided with your attempt, because it works perfectly for me. :)